# Firebase Trace Cancellation

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-performance

I want to measure the time of a task in my app using firebase performance traces; however, I don't want to include time when the user backgrounds the app.  I can't find a way to cancel the task if the task is no longer needed.

For example

1. I start the task
2. The user backgrounds the app
3. The user returns to the app
4. The task continues and completes

How do I ensure that the time the app was backgrounded doesn't affect my metrics?  I would assume throwing out those samples would work but there is no cancel method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you don't want a trace to be reported, simply don't call [`stop()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/perf/metrics/Trace.html#stop()) on it.  A Trace doesn't actively do anything at all until you do call `stop()`.